# How to create sublime submenu dynamically

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I am writing a sublime plugin for my own use.

We have several projects, each command may apply to each project.

I can hardcode these submenus, but it's not so good.

[image]

Can I create these project sub menu dynamically? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create menu items using `.sublime-menu` files - you could of course manually create/delete these using a plugin.

However, I would recommend simply hiding menu items that aren't relevant. The `TextCommand`, `WindowCommand` and `ApplicationCommand` all have an [`is_visible` method that can be overridden](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.WindowCommand). This method gets called every time a menu item references the command. By overriding this method, you can implement some logic to decide whether to show the menu item or not.